# I can't access data from my node server via POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, async-await, fetch

I made a node server with the three packages express, body-parser and cors.
I am trying to access data from client-side in my app.js with an async/await function that has a post request with the required data that I want to fetch

here's the fetch request and the post request in app.js, I am trying to pass the data [temperature, date, userResponse] via the postData function in app.js:

```
    //post routes
   const postData=async function postData(url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=', data = {}) {
    
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', 
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache', 
      credentials: 'same-origin', 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        
      },
      redirect: 'follow',
      referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
      body: JSON.stringify(data) 
    });
    return await response.json();
}
  
postData('/add', {temperature: '1', date: '2', userResponse: '2'});
}
```

and here's the server side code where I made an add route as post route:

```
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
projectData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes
const express = require('express');
// Start up an instance of app
const app = express();
/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('website'));
const port = 3000;


// Setup Server
const server=app.listen(port, ()=>{console.log(`running on localhost: ${port}`)});
app.get('/all', sendData);

function sendData (request, response) {
  response.send(projectData);
};

// TODO-ROUTES!
const data=[]

app.post('/add', function(req,res){
  data.push(req.body)
console.log(data)
})
```

here's what I got when I ran the project on localhost:3000

[image]

I want the the parameters temperature, date and userResponse to appear in the console
the errors at line 35 related to the post request are :

app.js:35 POST http://localhost:3000/add net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
app.js:48 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

never mind the errors at the two above lines related to the get request

in vs code I can see this(the temperature, date and userResponse appear in the terminal but don't appear in the localhost:3000 console in the browser):

[image]

I just need the client-side to pass data to server-side dynamically and not just pass the response in the server-side

Comment: You need to respond to the request.  In `app.post('/add'`  use for example `res.json({ success: true });` I think the `Fail to fetch` error is thrown due to the timeout since you do not response.

Comment: What is your question? As @Molda stated above, you should be responding to your POST request. Is that it?

Comment: @Molda ok the error disappeared but I can't see the temperature and other data in the console

Comment: @Pavlo I need to console.log data array in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending any response back from the server. Send some response as below

```
app.post('/add', function(req,res){
  data.push(req.body)
  console.log(data)
  return res.send({}); //return whatever response you need to send
})
```

Comment: shouldn't the data come from the client-side? I need to do that in the project, please check the client-side code

Comment: Which data? I can see you are already passing data here "body: JSON.stringify(data) "

Comment: can you see the postData function in client-side? I passed temperature, date, userResponse